# Como faço para adicionar valores em outra coluna na minha tabela com javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, table, maps-javascript-api

Eu estou usando append para gerar minha tabela, mas cada linha está sendo gerada por um `ForEach`, mas agora que eu consegui gerar a primeira coluna eu não tenho idéia de como gerar a outra

```
let TrackerList = document.getElementById('TrackerList');

firebase.database().ref('users').on('value', function (snapshot) {
  TrackerList.innerHTML += '';
  snapshot.forEach(function (item) {
     item.forEach(function (navigation) {
        result = navigation.val();
        result.map((resultado, index) => {
            var tr = document.createElement('tr');
            var td = document.createElement('td');      
            td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(resultado.params['campaign']))
             tr.appendChild(td);
             TrackerList.appendChild(tr);
             console.log(resultado)
           })
        })
     })
  })
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
   <table class="mdl-data-table mdl-js-data-table mdl-shadow--2dp">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Campanha</th>
            <th>Canal</th>
            <th>Tráfego</th>
            <th>Vendas</th>
            <th>Conversão</th>
            <th>LandingPage</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="TrackerList">
        </tbody>
   </table>
```

Comment: Esse é o Stack Overflow **em português** traduza sua pergunta ou a faça no [SOen](http://stackoverflow.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aí está um código de exemplo.
Você cria a linha (TR) e vai inserindo os dados (TD's) nessa linha e depois sobe a linha pra tabela (TrackerList).

Os dados de uma data table são um vetor, então basta inseri-los na ordem dos headers.

O primeiro header é a Campanha, então este deve ser a primeira célula de cada linha.
Gerei a tabela com números pra exemplificar.

Toma esse link também... Pode ser útil.

> [HTML DOM TableData Object - W3 Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_tabledata.asp)

```js
let TrackerList = document.getElementById('TrackerList');
  
  //Gerando dados falsos
  
  var x = 0;
  while(x < 5) { // Para cada linha
    var tr = document.createElement('tr');
    
    TrackerList.appendChild(tr);
    var y = 0;
    while(y < 6) { // Para cada coluna
      let td = document.createElement('td'); // Crio o dado
      td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(y)); // Passo o dado. No caso do seu exemplo foi o resultado[campaign] ou algo assim...
      
      // Isso aqui não é necessário, mas fiz pra você entender como funciona.
      if(y == 0) {
        td.headers = "Campanha";
      }else if(y==1) {
        td.headers = "Canal";
      }else if(y==2) {
        td.headers = "Tráfego";
      }else if(y==3) {
        td.headers = "Vendas";
      }else if(y==4) {
        td.headers = "Conversão";
      }else if(y==5) {
        td.headers = "LandingPage";
      }
      
      tr.appendChild(td); // Subo o td pra linha.
      y++;
    }
    TrackerList.appendChild(tr); // Subo a linha pra tabela, após adicionar todas as colunas.
    x++;
  }
  
  
  // Console log pra você entender melhor como trabalhar com table...
  
  console.log(TrackerList.rows);
  console.log(TrackerList.rows[0].cells);
  
  console.log(TrackerList.rows[0].cells[0].headers);
  console.log(TrackerList.rows[0].cells[1].headers);
  console.log(TrackerList.rows[0].cells[2].headers);
  console.log(TrackerList.rows[0].cells[3].headers);
  console.log(TrackerList.rows[0].cells[4].headers);
  console.log(TrackerList.rows[0].cells[5].headers);
```

```css
.zui-table {
    border: solid 1px #DDEEEE;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
    font: normal 13px Arial, sans-serif;
}
.zui-table thead th {
    background-color: #DDEFEF;
    border: solid 1px #DDEEEE;
    color: #336B6B;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: left;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #fff;
}
.zui-table tbody td {
    border: solid 1px #DDEEEE;
    color: #333;
    padding: 10px;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btnadd">add</button>
<table class="zui-table">
        <thead>
          <tr class="TrackerListHeader">
            <th>Campanha</th>
            <th>Canal</th>
            <th>Tráfego</th>
            <th>Vendas</th>
            <th>Conversão</th>
            <th>LandingPage</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="TrackerList">
        </tbody>
   </table>
```